How to use rpart to calculate predicted probabilities for multi-class decision trees?
I am using iris as an example to build a multi-class decision tree in R using rpart function. The outcome is transformed into numeric numbers. I want to get the predicted probabilities for the three classes. However, when predict() is used, I get an error as below.
data("iris")

iris$outcome <- ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", 1,
                        ifelse(iris$Species == "versicolor", 2,
                               ifelse(iris$Species == "virginica", 3, NA)))


my_model <- rpart::rpart(outcome ~ ., data = iris, method = "anova")
iris$predictions <- predict(my_model, newdata = iris, type = "prob")


Error in predict.rpart(my_model, newdata = iris, type = "prob") :
Invalid prediction for "rpart" object

I notice that some people will convert the Species into a factor, but I am wondering if there is a way to get the predicted probabilities for the three classes when the dataset is treated to build a regression tree. I need to compute AUC afterward (so the predicted probabilities are needed). If it's impossible, how different the trained classification tree is from a trained regression tree?
